# Calculation program with arithmetic operators

Tags: python

Defining the function (x,y,ops) where x and y are 2 numbers to be input into the function and ops is a variable that indicates which of the arithmetic operator (+, - , /  *) is used.

I am stuck with how to define the ops.

This is what I have so far and I am stuck :(

```
x=eval(input("x= "))
y=eval(input("y= "))


def func(x, y, ops):
    return x+y if ops==1
    elif return x-y is ops==1



print(func(x, y, ops))
```

Comment: Dont use eval for this `eval(input("x= "))`. It gives users a chance to execute malicious code. use either `int(input("x= "))` or `float(input("x= "))`.

Comment: Just take input from user on what operation they want. e.g. 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, etc.

Comment: But how do I put that into the code on what operation for the system to use? I think thats what I am confuse with:/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of functions, which gives you quite a bit of flexibility in adding or changing operations.

```
oper_dict = {
"*": lambda x,y:x*y, 
"+": lambda x,y:x+y,  
"-": lambda x,y:x-y, 
"/": lambda x,y:x/y if y !=0 else 'div by zero'
}

x = float(input("x= "))
y = float(input("y= "))
oper = input("operation (*, +, -, /): ")

answer = oper_dict.get(oper, lambda x,y: 'unkown operation')(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you! Still have to understand more of python coding haha but appreciate it! Have a good day:)

Comment: No problem. This may help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-store-function-as-dictionary-value/

Answer (score 3):

You can have the user just enter the symbol. You can compare it as a string.

```
def func(x, y, ops):
    if ops == '+':
        return x+y
    elif ops == '-':
        return x-y
    elif ops == '*':
        return x*y
    elif ops == '/':
        return x/y
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown op " + ops)

x = float(input('x= '))
y = float(input('y= '))
op = input('op [+,-,*,/]: ')

print(func(x, y, op))
```

Answer (score 1):

This presents a good opportunity to dig deeper into Python's fantastic standard libraries.  In this case the [operator library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) can be used to peform the desired calculator operations.  Using a dictionary you can use operation symbols as keys and the operations themselves as the values:

```
from operator import mul, add, sub, truediv

op_mapper = {"*": mul, "+": add, "-": sub, "/": truediv}

x = float(input("x= "))
y = float(input("y= "))
op = input("operator [*, +, -, /]: ")

print(op_mapper[op](x, y))
```

Comment: Haha this is so complex but I will try it out! This is smt new for me hehe thank u so much!! Have a good day!:)